# How to delete a document from cloud firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make this chat app where i want to add an unsend option (allowing the users to delete the messages they sent). I succeeded in getting the unsend option selected but now I cant figure out how to do these few things.

1. delete message (somehow get document id of selected message and delete it)
2. see if the message to be deleted was sent by the logged in user (this i can figure out on my own ig)

I cant seem to get hang of how to figure out the document id.

Heres the chat screen's code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:messenger/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
late User loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen({super.key});

  static String id = '/chat';

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late String messageText;

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: const Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            const MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesStream({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream:
          _fireStore.collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;
        List<Messagebubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.get('text');
          final messageSender = message.get('sender');

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = Messagebubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10.0,
              vertical: 20.0,
            ),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Messagebubble extends StatefulWidget {
  const Messagebubble(
      {required this.sender,
      required this.text,
      required this.isMe,
      super.key});

  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  State<Messagebubble> createState() => _MessagebubbleState();
}

class _MessagebubbleState extends State<Messagebubble> {
  late Offset tapXY;
  late RenderBox overlay;

  // void _getTapPosition(TapDownDetails details) {
  //   final RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  //   setState(() {
  //     tapXY = referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
  //   });
  // }

  void _getTapPosition(TapDownDetails detail) {
    tapXY = detail.globalPosition;
  }

  void _showContextMenu(BuildContext context) async {
    final RenderObject? overlay =
        Overlay.of(context)?.context.findRenderObject();

    final result = await showMenu(
        context: context,

        // Show the context menu at the tap location
        position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
            Rect.fromLTWH(tapXY.dx, tapXY.dy, 30, 30),
            Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, overlay!.paintBounds.size.width,
                overlay.paintBounds.size.height)),

        // set a list of choices for the context menu
        items: [
          const PopupMenuItem(
            value: 'unsend',
            child: Text('Unsend Message'),
          ),
        ]);

    // Implement the logic for each choice here
    switch (result) {
      case 'unsend':
        debugPrint('Add To Favorites');
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            widget.isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.sender,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (details) => _getTapPosition(details),
            onLongPress: () => _showContextMenu(context),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: widget.isMe
                    ? const Radius.circular(30)
                    : const Radius.circular(0),
                topRight: widget.isMe
                    ? const Radius.circular(0)
                    : const Radius.circular(30),
                bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(30),
              ),
              color: widget.isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  widget.text,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how about flutter/dart but in JavaScript you have ID in `documentSnapshot` you getting data from it by `.data()` and ID by `.id`.

Comment: the `id` should be stored in your chat model, otherwise, you can't delete it using the id. even if you can get the id by looping all of your chat collection, you still dont know the id of the one you are deleting. so what you can do is `delete by content`. but its not a good idea because you have to loop your whole collection in order to find the chat you want to delete. So what you have to do is add id to your chat model.

Comment: @john the thing is, as you can see the im using a gesture detector to detect the message bubble. how do i get the data inside that bubble?

Comment: your data is already in your `MessageBubble` constructor, `sender`, `text` and `isMe`. if that is the only data you saved to firestore, there is no more data you can retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, let's say you have a `DocuemntQuery` calles `doc_ref`, and we gor the snapshot from it :

```
DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await doc_ref.get();
```

you can get the `documentId` from the DocumentSnapshot like this :

```
var doc_id = docSnap.reference.documentID;
```

then you can delete that document with that id :

```
await _fireStore.collection(CollectioName).doc(doc_id).delete();
```

Comment: alright so in the code, the gesture detector detects when a message bubble is long pressed and shows an unsend option. How do i get the doc id of that message bubble?

Answer (score 1):

You need the ID of the message you want to delete.

```dart
Future<void> deleteMessage(String msgId) async {
  return await _fireStore.collection('messages').doc(msgId).delete();
}
```

See also the [docs for deleting Firestore data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) and the [references](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/delete.html).

Comment: yes the problem is IDK how to find the id. Any help on that?